# VS2017 Setup project - How to open the Setup Property Pages?

Tags: setup-project, visual-studio-2017

Tried to resolve the setup project warnings in VS2017:

> WARNING: Could not find prerequisite 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86
>   and x64)' in path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce
>   Bootstrapper\'
>
> WARNING: Could not find prerequisite 'Windows Installer
>   4.5' in path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\'

In VS2015 when I right click the Setup project in the solutions explorer it opens a new dialog "Setup Property Pages"
[image: Setup Property Pages]
here I can configure the prerequisites...

How can I configure the `Prerequisites` in VS2017? Right click on the setup project just jumps to the Properties Panel below the Solution Explorer Panel.

**EDIT Aug 2017**
With `VS2017 Version 15.3.2` and updated `Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects` extension -> "right click" - Properties - in the Solution Explorer works again like expected before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click properties won't work in setup project VS2017 like it worked in VS2015.

[image: Right click properties]

In VS2017 choosing `Setup Properties` from Project menu will open the `SetupProperty Pages` dialog as expect.

[image: Setup Properties from Project menu]

Comment: It's actually "<Setup Project Name> Properties", not just "Setup Properties".

Answer (score 1):

And then you may run into the error of vs telling you it cannot find a prerequisite like .net framework 4.5, etc. They are supposed to be downloaded and placed in a certain folder. If that is the case then see the example below for adding .netfx4.6.2:

1. Download the 4.6.2 offline installer file from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
2. Place the file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX462

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/10716/clickonce-can-not-find-462-prerequisite.html